# How to use the mounted ssh in docker for subsequent commands in Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, ssh, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I have to do a git push while running my container using CMD.
But the ssh is not available in the last line i.e in the CMD part, to do a git push.
What can I do here to get the ssh key for git push? Someone please help me.

Please find my **Dockerfile**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

# Install git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Clone private repository
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git myproject

CMD python myproject/src/example.py && git push
```

Then I use the following command to pass my ssh key during run

```
docker build --ssh default .
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As seen in "[BuildKit / Using SSH to access private data in builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds)" and "[Build secrets and SSH forwarding in Docker 18.09](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066)", I see that used with:

- `--mount=type=ssh`
- only on `RUN` lines, not `CMD`

So that would work with a `RUN`, during `docker build`.
That might not work at runtime (`docker run`) with a `CMD`

Answer (score 11):

Just for posterity, there are **3** prerequisites of this working, so make sure that build is using buildx, inside the `Dockerfile` you use the `RUN` command with `--mount=type=ssh` and you are passing `--ssh default` parameter to the build command:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

> FROM ...
> RUN --mount=type=ssh composer install --no-dev --no-interaction

```
docker build --ssh default .
```