# SSH agent forwarding can't find ssh-agent lock

Tags: docker, ssh

I am trying to set up ssh agent forwarding for docker build.

My build command:

`eval $(ssh-agent) && DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}`

Executing gives the following error:

`could not parse ssh: [default=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXX0RoNqr/agent.41017]: stat /tmp/ssh-XXXXXX0RoNqr/agent.41017: no such file or directory`

followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193650/how-to-use-the-mounted-ssh-in-docker-for-subsequent-commands-in-dockerfile) and tried removing `=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}` but the error persists